# OSX: Possible to use Total Terminal with iTerm2?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, terminal.app, iterm2

As I understand it, Total Terminal is a thin layer on top of Terminal.app that adds some [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/)-like features.

My question is: Is it possible to use Total Terminal with iTerm2 as the "backend" instead of Terminal.app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already the functionality, as Phoenix said, so no use for "changing the backend" of TotalTerminal. In iTerm2, just add a new profile with setting Window/Style/top of screen, add a global hotkey for toggling iTerm2 on this specific profile, and you're done.

See: http://technosophos.com/content/configure-iterm2-act-visor

Answer (score 3):

I was just wondering this as well, however iTerm2 has a visor implementation already built in.  It's not as nice as totalterminal's ( no animation, or autostart built in ) but it's workable.  Going to try it out for awhile and see if I can work out what little kinks I have with it.  If you find any tips or tricks let me know

Comment: I'm not seeing the visor implementation built into iTerm2. How do you activate it?

Comment: Not sure if they added it recently, but I have the animation working in my machine

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer states, there's no need to configure totalterminal to run iterm2, instead configure iterm2 to act like visor. The link in the accepted answer is broken. Here is a different one:

http://technosophos.com/2011/11/14/configure-iterm2-act-visor.html

Comment: This might be better posted as a comment to the accepted answer rather than creating a new one.